# Completely transparent image

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, gdi

Does anyone know how I can create a Completely transparent image or given am image (`HBITMAP`) how can I wipe it Completely so that all pixels in it are 100% transparent?

Thank you.

Comment: If the entire image is transparent, then why have an image at all?

Comment: I would like to use this image as a base for some other operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found the solution without the use of GDI+.

```
BITMAPV5HEADER bi = {sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER), 320, 240, 1, 32, BI_BITFIELDS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF, 0xFF000000};
HDC hDc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(0);

if(NULL != hDc)
{
    RGBQUAD* pArgb;
    HBITMAP tBmp = ::CreateDIBSection(hDc, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pArgb, NULL, 0);

    if(NULL != tBmp)
    {
        int x, y;
        DWORD pBits;

        pBits = (DWORD*)pArgb;
        for(y = 0; y < bi.bV5Height; y++)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < bi.bV5Width; x++)
            {
                *pBits = 0;
                pBits++;
            }
        }
    }
    ::DeleteObject(hDc);
}
```

tBmp will be a 320 x 240 bitmap that is completely transparent

Answer (score 2):

The bitmap needs to be 32-bit so it has an alpha channel that you can set opacity values with.  If your image is not 32-bit, you will have to create a new 32-bit bitmap and copy the original pixels into it.

Comment: The question is how do I create this image and how do I set the opacity value? 'CreateBitmap' does not give me any way of setting the opacity.

Comment: `CreateBitmap()` allows you to create a 32-bit bitmap, but there is no API for setting a pixel's opacity afterwards. You have to manipulate the pixel data directly. `CreateBitmap()` returns a pointer to the raw pixel data, which is a two-dimensional array of pixels.  For a 32-bit bitmap, each pixel will be 4 bytes, making every 4th byte in the data an alpha channel of a particular pixel.

Comment: Can you point me to any example of setting the 4th byte? This is a pure API application.

Comment: Just type-cast the data pointer returned by `CreateBitmap()` to an `RGBQUAD*` pointer, then you can loop through the array updating the values as needed. The `RGBQUAD.rgbReserved` field is the alpha channel of each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a monochrome bitmap as a mask to create transparent images from colour ones. This is quite complex. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94961) example (in VB but uses Win32 APIs directly)

Alternatively, the [TransparentBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function might make what you're trying to do unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in GDI+. The best way to do this is to attach the device context of the image that you are working with with GDI+ graphic object and then call its clear method.